# Запрос одного параметра из списка в requests

Tags: python, requests

Как из этого списка `https://api.vime.world/online/staff` можно вернуть только одно значение username? Пытался делать так: `modersGet.json().get("username")` и так `modersGet.json()["username"].get([0])` где `modersGet = requests.get("https://api.vime.world/online/staff")` . Если быть короче:

Как из списка вернуть одно значение через requests?

Comment: [0]["username"] очевидно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сначала выбираете элемент из списка по индексу. Каждый такой элемент - словарь. Из этого словаря можно получить значение по ключу.

```
In [7]: r = requests.get('https://api.vime.world/online/staff')

In [8]: usernames = [i.get('username') for i in r.json()]

In [9]: usernames
Out[9]: 
['Bestbody',
 'PeppiOnKiva',
 'KosharaMeoW',
 '3Jlou_Ra1ple',
 'Bllinkers',
 'flowerrose',
 'bunnyscopper',
 'Mishytkaaa']

In [10]: r.json()[0].get('username')
Out[10]: 'Bestbody'

In [11]: r.json()[1].get('username')
Out[11]: 'PeppiOnKiva'

In [12]: r.json()[2].get('username')
Out[12]: 'KosharaMeoW'
```